# Linux split command distorts UTF-8 characters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, utf-8, split

I want to split a large tagged text file into smaller ones so that I can manipulate them in Python. The large text file contains Arabic texts in `UTF-8` format. From the `bash shell`. I  run the following command

`split --bytes=2M -d --additional-suffix=.txt large_file.txt file`

The expected output is Arabic text, but I get several files containing output like below
`Ø£Ù/NN ÙØ°ÙØ±Ø/VBP ØªÙÙÙØ©Ù/NN ÙÙÙØ§ØŠØ¯Ø©Ø/NN Ø£ÙÙ/NN ÙØ¯/RP ÙÙØ¹/V`

When trying to load these files into python, it throws error message `can't decode character at position xxx etc.`
The question is: how can I make `split` command maintain the `UTF-8` format?

I am using `Linux Mint Qiana 17 KDE` distribution.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `wc -l ` first to get a line count on the file and then split using `split −l line_count` where `line_count` is an appropriate divisor of the output of `wc -l`?

Comment: @user3439894 thank you for good suggestion. It worked. The file contains more than 2 million lines and I split it into several files, each file contains 100 thousand lines. `UTF-8` was preserved, too. Thank you again.

Comment: In your first attempts you probably split in the middle of a multi-byte UTF-8 character. The first file in which it happens is OK (but the last character) but the next files are broken.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet, That's exactly what happened and is why I suggested using line count vs. file size with split, as that's the way it should be done in a use case such as this.

Comment: @user3439894, sure. I added this comment because _give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime_